# HashMap<Integer, Object> get method

Tags: java, integer, hashmap, key, int

I understand that the java.util.HashMap can only accept Objects as keys and thus cannot accept a primitive int but instead only accepts Integer objects.

When using the get method to retrieve the value by using the key as a parameter must you put in an Integer object? Or will a primitive int suffice here?

Comment: If you need a Map of <Integer,Object> see if you can use an array of Object instead.

Comment: The Integer is a reference number for the Object. So I'm not referencing the object by the position in the list but by its reference number. If I used an array and removed an element in the middle then the number for that object would change if it was after the object that was removed in the list. However this object must have a consistent key. Also all the items that could be in the list with their reference may not all be in the list at any one time. That was my thought process on why not to use an array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Java 5+ a primitive `int` will be autoboxed into an `Integer`, so it's safe to use it; prior to this you'll need to use an object

Comment: What happened before java 5? Threw Exception?

Comment: @Zim-ZamO'Pootertoot: That doesn't actually matter; generics themselves are new to 1.5

Comment: @noMAD: Before 1.5, that would be a compiler error (cannot convert `int` to `Integer`)

Comment: Thanks a lot :) I am also interested as to what happened before java 5

Comment: @DanMc prior to Java 5, you had to do `Integer integer = new Integer(anInt); anotherIntVar = integer.intValue();` manually.

Comment: @nachokk that also works but for `String` only. Refer to [the old Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html)